# ASP.NET MVC2 Membership: How to get userID and roleID of logged user?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, membership, userid

How can I get userID and roleID of user that is logged to application? `User.Identity` doesn't contain these details?

Thanks,
Ile

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's how:

```
string userId = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString();
string[] roleNames = Roles.GetRolesForUser(username);
```

Answer (score 4):

Another good one to know is:

```
bool isAdmin =  Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this too :

```
List<String> roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser().ToList();
```